# Converting c# .net string List into html dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

So I made a list of string in my c# .net application and I would like to store this list in a html dropdown. First of, I have no idea if I have done it right in my view, I have set my list but I have no idea if there are steps missing. My code is as follow :

```
        CalendarFolder calendar = ewsconn.Calendar;
        ExchangeService service = ewsconn.Service;
        Calendars = ewsconn.Calendars; 
        foreach (var c in Calendars)
        {
            calendarNames.Add(c.DisplayName);                            
        }
        foreach (var s in calendarNames)
        {
            Response.Write(s + "<br />");
        }
        getCalendarList(calendarNames);
```

This is a list of every calendar folder names from x user in Microsoft exchange api. I need to use that list in a html dropdown to use it later on. Do I return it properly? Is there any steps I am missing along the way? My getCalendarList only returns the list I give it, it does nothing special.

In my javascript, the only value I am capable of getting is the Response.write from my code above. See code below:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: '/domain/Crm/getCalendars.aspx?email=' + useremail,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);            
      }
 });
```

Now I know there is a lot missing here, but I know I need to convert my c# list into an array to then use it in my html code, but how do I do it?
I have tried this from the research I made :

```
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(getCalendars.calendarNames));
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        alert(array[i]); // should display "calendar1" then "calendar2" etc
```

but to be honest I don't know the proper syntax and I couldn't not get it to work.

Kind of a long wall of text but some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: A good way to quickly determine if you missed any steps is to test it. What happens when you do?

Comment: Your ActionResult could return Json(object) then you would be able to access the result as a JSON object. (assuming you're using MVC). If you're not yhrn you coudl use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize your object into a JSON strign that you coudl then write out.

Comment: I have an alert but it uses my response.write output. Ajax executes when I press a button, then my alert goes : calendar1calender2calender3calender4. My list is not used.
 
My Json does nothing.

Comment: Why not make a static helper method that returns the List<strings> and then iterate in your ui.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(--C# list--))` should work, if your C# list is valid. From there you can just populate the options in your select with the values.

But you can maybe make it work inside that ajax. You could add a comma after every entry, then split the response.

```
...
success: function (data) {
    options = data.split(',')
    //build the dropdown     
}
...
```